# Cannot remove npm

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

I could not remove npm

When I check do the following command
`which npm`
the output is
`/snap/bin/npm`

but when I try to do
`sudo apt-get remove npm`

It is showing no package found.

Also when trying to use npm commands the system is not giving any output

Answer (score 2):

You installed `npm` using snap, it seems. Try using the `snap` package manager:

```
sudo snap remove npm
```